# Parse subtitle(srt) with regexp

Tags: regex

I want to parse subtitle with regexp. But not match multi line text.

Regexp Code:

```
(?<order>(\d+))\n(?<start>([\d:,]+))[\s-{2}\>]+(?<end>([\d:,]+))\n(?<text>(.+|\n))
```

https://regex101.com/r/jV9oV2/2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(?<order>\d+)\n(?<start>[\d:,]+)\s+-{2}\>\s+(?<end>[\d:,]+)\n(?<text>[\s\S]*?(?=\n{2}|$))
```

You can modify your regex this way to grab `text`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/jV9oV2/3